# Javascript, generate result to text file

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

This is a sample javascript code from http://locationdetection.mobi to detect geo location using google API.
(Original zip file contains a php file, html, and this javascript code)

As you see in the code below, on the last part of this javascript code there is one line of code to render the result of location detection to html file.
How to generate result into a text file instead of render to browser?

```
// this is called when the browser has shown support of navigator.geolocation
function GEOprocess(position) {
  // update the page to show we have the lat and long and explain what we do next
  document.getElementById('geo').innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + ' Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude;
  // now we send this data to the php script behind the scenes with the GEOajax function
  GEOajax("geo.php?accuracy=" + position.coords.accuracy + "&latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude +"&altitude="+position.coords.altitude+"&altitude_accuracy="+position.coords.altitudeAccuracy+"&heading="+position.coords.heading+"&speed="+position.coords.speed+"");
}

// this is used when the visitor bottles it and hits the "Don't Share" option
function GEOdeclined(error) {
  document.getElementById('geo').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + error.message;
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GEOprocess, GEOdeclined);
}else{
  document.getElementById('geo').innerHTML = 'Your browser sucks. Upgrade it.';
}

// this checks if the browser supports XML HTTP Requests and if so which method
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else if(window.ActiveXObject){
  xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// this calls the php script with the data we have collected from the geolocation lookup
function GEOajax(url) {
 xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
 xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// this reads the response from the php script and updates the page with it's output
function updatePage() {
 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
  var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = '' + response;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't create text files from the frontend, well at least not without configuring some flags in the browser, so you need to send the data to your backend language, create the file and then download it